# Ajax Binding a Kendo Grid with Asp.Net MVC doesn't display anything

Tags: asp.net, ajax, binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to bind a Kendo Grid with Asp.Net MVC. I show that grid in a detail page View with a lot of other fields... 
The records are coming correctly but nothing is displayed in the grid.

Here is the Grid code, in the user control (ascx), of the View:

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<Web.Areas.WorkOrder.ViewModels.PartListViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
   columns.Bound(p => p.GlassType);
   columns.Bound(p => p.WorkType);
   columns.Bound(p => p.PartNumber);
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Read(read => read.Action("GetPartListInfo", "Claim", new { id = Model.JobId }))
.PageSize(5)
.ServerOperation(false)
)
 .Pageable()
 .Sortable()
 .Groupable()
 .Filterable()
 .Render();                                  
%>
```

The Model View looks like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<PartListViewModel> PartList { get; set; }
    public string VIN { get; set; }
    public string Invoice { get; set; }
    public string MileageKM { get; set; }
    public EntityModel Provider { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    …etc, etc
```

This is the code from my Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetPartListInfo([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string id)
    {
        XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext();
        workorder workOrder = xrmServiceContext.workorderSet.Where(i => i.Id == new Guid(id)).FirstOrDefault();

        IEnumerable<PartListViewModel> parts = (xrmServiceContext.workorderproductSet.Where(prod => prod.WorkOrder.Id == workOrder.Id))
            .Select(x => new PartListViewModel
            {
                WOId = id,
                Id = x.f1_Product.Id.ToString(),
                Quantity = 3,
                PartNumber = "WS",,                    
                WorkType = "Repair", 
                GlassType = "Windshield",
                Price = 133
            }).ToList();

        return Json(parts.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Am I missing something in my configuration? I am wondering what is going wrong with it? 
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you sure records are coming correctly? What is the situtation in the network tab of your browser? Whats the exact response for that particular Ajax request?

Comment: Yes, I am, the records are coming correctly. When I am returning only Json data with second parameter JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, the data in JSON format is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to allow a get:

```
return Json(parts.ToDataSourceResult(request),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it works now but I also added a new instance of DataSourceResult and set the Data and Total properties to the processed data and total number of records.

Comment: Hi user could you answer this issue i am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44276293/kendo-ui-mvc-basic-ajax-binding