# Kendo UI MVC - basic ajax binding

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I saw the example referred [here](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding#getting-started)

So in my application I try to implement it this way:

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult About([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
       List<ShortDetail> listSD = new List<ShortDetail>();
       ... fill the list with objects

       var v = listSD.ToDataSourceResult(request, sd => new ShortDetail { firstname = sd.firstname, surname = sd.surname, classname = sd.classname});

           return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
     }
```

**My Model ShortDetail**

```
public class ShortDetail 
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public int classid { get; set; }
    public string classname { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
    public int studentid { get; set; }
    public DateTime birthdate { get; set; }
    public int? indicatorID { get; set; }
    public string indicatorDescription { get; set; }
    public List<ResultMergedWithType> results { get; set; }
```

}

In my **View About.cshtml**

```
 <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoExample.Models.ShortDetail>().Name("grid").DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("About", "Home"))).Pageable())


</div>
```

Now i get raw json in browser

Alternatively if i try to bind the model with view

**About.cshtml**

```
@model List<KendoExample.Models.ShortDetail>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

 <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoExample.Models.ShortDetail>().Name("grid").DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("About", "Home"))).Pageable())


</div>
```

**HomeController**

```
 public ActionResult About([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
 {
   ...
   return View(listSD);
 }
```

then there is an empty grid with all columns as defined in model shortdetails except the ResultMergedWithType property[image]

Comment: are you sure you are getting values in `var v = listSD.ToDataSourceResult(request, sd => new ShortDetail { firstname = sd.firstname, surname = sd.surname, classname = sd.classname});`?

Comment: yes i am getting data in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was missing..we have to specify a data source in Grid<..>() constructor

**About.cshtml**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoExample.Models.ShortDetail>(Model).Name("grid").DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("About", "Home"))).Pageable())
```

**HomeController**

```
 public ActionResult About([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
 {
   ... 
   return View(listSD);
 }
```

It's ironic though that kendo support team was unable to help me with this problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have missed a step in the tutorial. You haven't declared your column schema (step 9) anywhere:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoExample.Models.ShortDetail>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("About", "Home")))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.firstname);
        columns.Bound(c => c.surname); ... 
    }
    .Pageable())
```

This is required to bind the data to the relevant columns.

Comment: No defining columns does not help in populating the table..tried that

Answer (score 0):

change your code while you returning the result using json from `return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` to `return Json(v.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

for that you need to add a namespace  `using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;`

Comment: Hey TechVision if you see my code above i am doing it already and browser is showing me raw json data only...what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think @TechVision is correct. I haven't tested it but you may be using that extension method incorrectly. I have a similar setup and the only difference in the code is :

```
List<SomeObject> items =  new GetSomeObjects();
return Json(items.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you still get the error after the change above then you are probably using the extension method correctly and I would open up web debugger and look at the source of the request and see if you are calling your controller method somewhere else in your code like `BeginForm()` or elsewhere.